# Android Studio Network Connection: int cannot be converted to void

Tags: java, android

I am trying to connect to a server via http in an Android app in Android Studio. This code comes right from the android studio website. However when I go to run I get the error "varargs mismatch; Int cannot be converted to void" from the publishProgress methods.

Here is the method with the error:

```
    private String downloadUrl(URL url) throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = null;
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // Timeout for reading InputStream arbitrarily set to 3000ms.
        connection.setReadTimeout(3000);
        // Timeout for connection.connect() arbitrarily set to 3000ms.
        connection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        // For this use case, set HTTP method to GET.
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        // Already true by default but setting just in case; needs to be true since this request
        // is carrying an input (response) body.
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        // Open communications link (network traffic occurs here).
        connection.connect();
        publishProgress(DownloadCallback.Progress.CONNECT_SUCCESS);
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode != HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new IOException("HTTP error code: " + responseCode);
        }
        // Retrieve the response body as an InputStream.
        stream = connection.getInputStream();
        publishProgress(DownloadCallback.Progress.GET_INPUT_STREAM_SUCCESS, 0);
        if (stream != null) {
            // Converts Stream to String with max length of 500.
            result = readStream(stream, 500);
        }
    } finally {
        // Close Stream and disconnect HTTPS connection.
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is the publishProgress method from the Android os:

```
    @WorkerThread
protected final void publishProgress(Progress... values) {
    if (!isCancelled()) {
        getHandler().obtainMessage(MESSAGE_POST_PROGRESS,
                new AsyncTaskResult<Progress>(this, values)).sendToTarget();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this comes from the `0` you pass as argument to the second `publishProgress` call.

Comment: All of them return that error

Comment: Can you post the code where you are creating the task ?, Maybe you have set the Progress type to Void while creating the task.

Comment: Still very new to this, not sure what you mean by the task :S